# collision test for 2d polygon physics

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, collision, intersection, game-physics

I want to do some 2D rigid body (polygon) physics and I've found an elaborate equation to calculate the collision response. But, before that I would need a good way of finding 'input' to that procedure of response.

I think such input should be coordinates of collision point and normal to the collision edge 
at this point. There are many algorithms to do collision detection. For example, I could test if some vertex of polygon A is inside the polygon B but it will not give me a normal to the edge. Then I could probably test intersection of edges in loop - but is this the simplest way or maybe there is something simpler?

Answer (score 0):

`Normal to the edge` depends on the `polygon only`. It's not a collision data.

Depending on how the polygon is defined in the program, you can get the normal from it.

Suppose it's defined by an array of vertex points.

An edge takes two consecutive points, witch define a straight line (the edge)
The edge's vector is thus:

```
EdgeVectorX = SecondPointX - FirstPointX
EdgeVectorY = SecondPointY - FirstPointY
```

The normal vetor to this you get changing X for Y and making one of them negative:

```
NormalX = -EdgeVectorY
NormalY =  EdgeVectorX
```

To make it a 1 lenght vector, divide both NormalX and NormalY by vector's length:

```
Length = SquareRoot(NormalX*NormalX + NormalY*NormalY)
```

---

About checking if vertex is inside some polygon, be sure to test if there aren't any other vertices inside. 
In case of more than one point, you'd have to interpolate the actual position with the previous position to find the exact moment of single vertex collision. (Only exception is the lucky case of edge-to-edge parallel collision). The bigger the time step you're using, the bigger mistakes.

The absurd mistake is when time step is big enough to make polygons go through each other without collision being detected.

Comment: it is colision data becouse coliding edge is a colision data, ;-)

Comment: ...anyway, there's how you get normal vector from an edge given by First and Second point.